# Genetic Algorithm to determine optimal trading action with Java

Tags: java, genetic-programming, technical-indicator

Genetic Algorithm in Java to combine the output of the trading signals,the task is to evolve a set of weights (one for each trading signal) to determine an optimal trading action.The individual representation     should associate a numeric weight  (between    0   and 1)  to  each trading signal.At the  end of the  evolutionary process, the best  weight  configuration   should  be  returned.

Comment: sample input ??

Comment: Here's the sample input

Comment: Trading Signals: T1= SELL, T2= SELL, T3= HOLD, T4= BUY

Comment: Use  a  GA  to  combine  the  output  of  the  trading  signals  from  the above.  For  the above; the 
indicator generate the following signals:
T1 => SELL
T2 => SELL
T3 => HOLD
T3 => BUY
In this case, you choose to SELL since the majority of trading signals are recommending 
this action. We say that all signals have the same weight in this case.

Comment: The task  is  to  implement  a  GA  to  evolve  a  set  of  weights  (one  for  each  trading  signal)  to 
determine  an  optimal  trading  action.  Your  individual  representation  should  associate  a 
numeric weight (between 0 and 1) to each trading signal, e.g.:
0.4 x Task 2a => BUY
0.2 x Task 2b => BUY
0.1 x Task 2c => HOLD
0.8 x Task 2d => SELL

Comment: Note that the sum of the signals does not need to add up to 1.
In the case above, the strategy decides to SELL, given that it is the signal associated with the 
highest  weight: BUY  =  0.4  +  0.2,  HOLD  =  0.1  and  SELL  =  0.8.

Comment: Your  implementation  should 
include:
• individual  representation  :  for  correct  representation,  one  weight  value 
between 0 and 1 per trading signal;

Comment: • fitness  function  :  for  correct  evaluation  of  candidate  solutions.  The  fitness 
function should operate with an initial budget of £1000 and stock amount of 0.

Comment: For each 
value on the training data, it should generate a trading signal. Every BUY action should 
deduct the amount from the budget and only be performed if there is sufficient budget, 
and increase the stock amount; every SELL action should deduct the stock amount and 
only  be  performed  if  there  is  sufficient  stocks,  and  increase  the  budget  accordingly; 
HOLD actions have no effect. The fitness of a solution is the total balance at the end of 
trading (budget + stock), where the stocks should be converted to cash using the last 
value of the training period;

Comment: • selection method : the GA should use tournament selection;
• genetic operators : the GA should use one mutation and one crossover operator 
of your choice. The mutation operator should only generate values between 0 and 1;
• termination criteria : a maximum number of generations should indicate the end 
of the evolutionary process.At the end of the evolutionary process, the best weight configuration should be returned.